# Do loop and print result if found, else do loop again: how to get rid of multiple nesting if's in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, nested

I have a dictionary with thousands of elements of the following structure:

```
    full_dict={'A': ['B','C','D','E'],
     'B':['A','C','D','E','F','X']
     'X':['W','Y','Z','S'],
     'S':['W','K','T'],
    ...}
```

where every letter is a word.
Every word can be both a key and a value (together with other words) for another dict element.

I am trying to find a "path" from one word to another. For example a path from 'A' to 'S' is A-B-X-S as S is among values of X, X in B and B in A.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
    query=['A','S']
    if 'S' in full_dict['A']:
        print ('Found during 1st iteration')
    else:
        for i in full_dict['A']:
            if 'S' in full_dict[i]:
                print ('Found during 2nd iteration')
            else:
                for ii in full_dict[i]:
                etc.
```

I do 10 iterations and it works fine but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems like a graph question...

Comment: What exactly is graph question?

Comment: See the answer given

Answer (score 1):

You can use `networkx` package:

```py
import networkx as nx
full_dict={'A': ['B','C','D','E'],
           'B': ['A','C','D','E','F','X'],
           'X': ['W','Y','Z','S'],
           'S': ['W','K','T'],
           }

g = nx.DiGraph() # directed graph
for k, v in full_dict.items():
    g.add_edges_from((k, to) for to in v)

print(*nx.all_simple_paths(g, 'A', 'S')) # ['A', 'B', 'X', 'S']
```

A (nested) loop wouldn't work in general because it will involve a  lot of nests (at best), and at worst, we don't generally know how many nests we would need.

Because of this, one could think of recursion instead. But this could be complicated since you might need to put much effort into things like breaking potential infinite loops or remembering intermediate results (to reduce computations).

So in my opinion, the best approach is a package that readily makes use of the graph structure of your data.

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn more about networkx. The solution that you suggested works amazing if the dict is small. But for the dict that I need to analyze it will take forever I guess. It's been running now for more that an hour already. I think it's because it's searching for all possible paths, which in my case will be millions.

Answer (score 0):

External libs are useful if you're doing this for production and need the high performance, optimizations, all possible paths, etc.

If you're doing this as an exercise or something where you can be sure of clean input (no loops within the word lists) or don't want an external lib for just one operation, then you can try a recursion:

```py
full_dict = {
     'A': ['B','C','D','E'],
     'B': ['A','C','D','E','F','X'],
     'X': ['W','Y','Z','S'],
     'S': ['W','K','T'],
}

def find_path(source, target):
     for key, words in full_dict.items():
          if target in words:
               yield target
               if key == source:  # check if it's source
                    yield source
               else:
                    # otherwise, look for this key as new target
                    yield from find_path(source, key)
               break  # prevent further checking of remaining items
```

Usage:

```py
list(find_key('A', 'S'))
# ['S', 'X', 'B', 'A']

# get it in the right order, reverse it
list(find_key('A', 'S'))[::-1]
# ['A', 'B', 'X', 'S']
```

The approach looks for the target word in the word list and then yields each key. Rather than check the word lists possible for every word in the source - since that creates many chains that may or may not get to the target.

More info on [`yield` expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions).

Note that [Python3's recursion limit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) is 1000, by default. So if the word chain may be longer, either increase the limit or use another method. Setting the limit to 4 and using this modified dict `full_dict = {'A': ['B', 'D', 'E'], 'B': ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'X'], 'X': ['W', 'Y', 'Z', 'C'], 'C': ['W', 'K', 'T', 'S'], 'S': []}`, you'd hit the limit for A to S which is now a chain of 5 (`['A', 'B', 'X', 'C', 'S']`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Simple and efficient! The only limitation is that it does not give you all possible paths because of recursion limit

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a recursive function:

```
def findLink(path,target,links):
    if not isinstance(path,list): path = [path] # start path with initial word
    for linked in links.get(path[-1],[]):       # go through links of word
        if linked == target: return path+[target] # done, return full path
        if linked in path: continue               # avoid circular linking
        foundPath = findLink(path+[linked], target,links) # dig deeper
        if foundPath: return foundPath            # reached end on that path
```

output:

```
full_dict={'A': ['B','C','D','E'],
     'B':['A','C','D','E','F','X'],
     'X':['W','Y','Z','S'],
     'S':['W','K','T'] }

print(findLink('A','S',full_dict))
['A', 'B', 'X', 'S']
```